# Avocode / Ceros Inspect alternative

Tags: css, code-generation, adobe-xd

since Avocode and also Ceros Inspect software was sunset recently, is there any good alternative for software that opens Adobe XD files and generates CSS codes?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Figpea.com](https://figpea.com/), I've found this one pretty similar to Inspect. Also web-based, PSD support and shows CSS properties.

Upd: [Photopea.com](https://www.photopea.com/) is useful too, shows more detailed CSS.

Comment: Thank you, it looks quite good. It is not powerful as Avocode before, but it has potential to the future.